# get Activity() not working in Appcompat Version 1.3.0

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a `fragment` in the `Activity`. I want to access the `Activity` variable from `fragment`.

**In Activity Code(MyActivity.java):**

```
public String name = "smackalpha"
```

**In fragment:**

```
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
String retrievedName = myActivity.name;
```

This code is working great in Appcompat Version 1.2.0

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

But After updating to the latest version, `retrievedName` gets `null` value.

**Latest version:**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

Then how to get value from `activity` in `Fragment`. Please help me with some solutions. I saw several answers. Everyone suggests this way only. I have tried `requireActivity()` also

Comment: Are you trying to pass the string between activity to fragment right?

Comment: `requireActivity()` is working in appcompat:1.3.0, I can confirm that, I'm using it and it's working fine.

Comment: @Ajithkumarmuthukumaran, yes

Comment: There are some changes how e.g. fragment lifecycle works in androidx. However it can't explain this with the code given - when exactly are you setting the value for `name` and when are you reading it?

Comment: try this ```public static String name = "smackalpha";```

Comment: @laalto, I am setting the value globally in activity. I want to read it in fragment.

Comment: First, check a few things.. in which method of the fragment you are accessing the activity data.. make sure getActivity is not null/ or it's a `MyActivity`.. Make sure nothing is changing the variable value(like dynamic string allocation to that string variable)..